# Storing multiple coordinates in a single entry in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I couldn't find this by doing some research so I decided to ask it here.

My problem is that I want to store routes (begin, checkpoints, end) in a database. Each point has x, y and z location (float in C), possibly an angle (also float x, y, z) and horizontal & vertical sizes. There are a maximum of 22 points (begin, end, 20 checkpoints). Currently I've done it with the following kind of text file:

```
[begin]
posx = 1230.169800
posy = 2459.526611
posz = -86.520058
angx = 20.961914
angy = 19.720459
angz = 0.000000

[end]
posx = 3784.660400
posy = 7311.252930
posz = -489.097229
angx = 9.080200
angy = 93.345337
angz = 0.000000
horizontal = 100
vertical = 100

[cp]
posx = 2871.044189
posy = 3165.119141
posz = -541.189758
angx = 0.000000
angy = 0.000000
angz = 0.000000
horizontal = 100
vertical = 100

[cp]
posx = 2328.984375
posy = 4327.809082
posz = -254.201324
angx = 0.000000
angy = 0.000000
angz = 0.000000
horizontal = 100
vertical = 100
```

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to store this kind of data in SQLite. One thing I could think of is having one text column for each point (22, quite a lot) and parsing them when a single route is loaded.

Another way I could think of was storing each point as a single entry and then linking them to the route entry. This way I'd still need 22 columns for the foreign keys.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance,
Jussi

Comment: Your second solution with a slight modification should work. The route can be created as a table like `route_id, from_node, to_node`, where the starting point has `from_node` and destination has `end_node` set to null. You can query and retrieve the path later.

Comment: I didn't really understand how would it handle the checkpoints? I would have the begin and the end, but what about the checkpoints?

Comment: An example would be `101-NULL-1, 101-1-2, 101-2-3, 101-3-4, 101-4-5, 101-5-NULL`. Lets say the route_id is 101, it starts from Node_id = 1 and ends at Node_id = 5, while passing through nodes 2, 3 and 4, in that order. This is essentially a representation of a graph in a database.

Comment: To re-construct a path you have to loop through the result from the table, because sqlite doesn't have CTEs. In MSSQL Server you can use CTEs and reconstruct the path in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option you mentioned can be used with slight modification if you add sequence number of point in the root (where begin point will have `sequence_number=0` and end will have max `sequence_number`):

```
create table route (id integer primary key,
  // other fields like name, etc
);

create table point (
   id integer primary key,
   route_id integer,
   sequence_number integer not null,
   posx real not null,
   posy real not null,
   posz real not null,
   angx real not null,
   angy real not null,
   angz real not null,
   horizontal null,
   vertical null,
   CONSTRAINT route_fk FOREIGN KEY(route_id) REFERENCES route(id)
);
```